# ASP.NET MVC Role authorisation with custom login page and database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, model-view-controller

I'm creating an app with a login page that compares the password with the password stored in the database. I'm using a superclass Person, with 3 subclasses: Admin, Trainer and Member. My goal is to get a login page, that redirects the person to a homepage, where they have an overview of their profile. If the person is an admin, they also have access to an admintools button, which takes them to a new page with admin-only tools.

During class we learned that Asp.Net has built-in role authorization and a registration/login page by default. The problem is that we need to keep track of users, their password, location, their role,... in a database and I have no idea if this is possible with the default login/registration/roles.

Passwords aren't created by the user, but are instead handed out by the admin, who also has to keep track of users and their password.

Is it possible to keep track of all those things with the default registration/login page and would using those defaults be better than creating my own loginpage? If it's better to create my own loginpage, wouldn't that cause me trouble with role authorization?

Comment: All these can be done using identity in asp.net core. I think you should read about identity in Asp.net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity covers all your mentioned requirements and many more. More importantly, it is highly customizable. So, I personally recommend using Identity and customize it whenever you need.